# how to move to other section in script

Tags: bots, gupshup

I'm building a bot using gupshup.io using the scripting way ... but handling some things in default.js file as mentioned in the docs 
I'm trying in a handler function to check if the event.message equals specific string to go to another section in the script 
can anybody please help ? 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to achieve that you can create a child state to go another section and just set options.next_state to that state. I mean suppose you have a script like this

```
[main]
    inputParser:Welcome to New Bot.
            thisFlow:
                This is a output of this flow.
            callAnotherFlow:
                :call default.anotherFlow
[anotherFlow]
    This is another flow.[[Wow, No]]
        Wow
            Thanks
        No
            Oh!
```

So in case if the message is 'another flow' you want the second flow to begin. So in the input parser you can create something like.

```
module.exports.main = {
    inputParser: (options, event, context, callback)=>{
        if(event.message.toLowerCase() === "another flow"){
            options.next_state = 'callAnotherFlow';
        }else{
            options.next_state = 'thisFlow';
        }
        callback(options, event, context);
    }
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.